# Steam mobile authenticator on a Windows phone

Tags: steam, steam-mobile, windows-phone

My question is essentially the title, can you get a mobile authenticator on a Windows phone?

Also related do you need the app for the mobile authenticator? I can't find any information either way but I think you do.

Comment: I'd really want a Windows Phone authenticator for the simple fact that I want the achievement related to it. In order to become Community Ambassador you need to do 28 out of 29 tasks. The two I'm missing right now are the Two-factor Authenticator and the Post a video. I don't think I'll post a video soon...

Comment: @Aventinus Not just that but I used to do quite a bit of trading, can't now as no one trusts you if you don't have an authenticator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Steam Guard on my Lumia 950XL which has Win 10 Phone OS.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/steam/9nblggh4x7gm

Guard works perfect from here, just annoying Family Protection, but it was my decision.

Recommend to all of you.

P.S,
i know question is old, but it is still good to have correct answer.
And I'm using Steam on it for year at least, may be more. So it was there around 2016, since May at least.

Comment: Nice to see they actually got around to releasing an app for Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I assume it happened during the period when they tried to force everyone on using Guard for Community Market and so on. And there was a hype on sub-forum with App request for WinPhones, because without it many people could not really trade on market.

Answer (score 5):

The instructions for [Steam Guard: How to set up a Steam Guard Mobile Authenticator](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4440-RTUI-9218) on Steam's own website make it pretty clear that only Android and iOS are supported - there is zero mention of Windows Phone.

In either case, it's part of the Steam Mobile app.

Comment: That's what I thought. But you mean it is part of the app, as in I can't get text alerts?

Comment: There is no option for text alerts I'm aware of.